# Pass data from vue file to js file in vuejs?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

In file : `Product.vue`

```
beforeCreate() {
      const productId = this.$route.params.id;
    axios
      .get("/localhost/api/product/" + productId)
      .then((res) => {
        console.log(res.data); // result : {name: 'Iphone', status: 3, quantity: 100, price: 800}
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
      });
  },
```

I have a file `productData.js` on the same level as `Product.vue`. Now I want to transfer data of `res.data` through `productData.js`, how to do? In other words in productData.js I want to get the result of `res.data` when I call the API. Thanks.

update :

```
let data = null;

function initData(apiRes) {
  data = apiRes;
  console.log(data); // Output: "Hi from server"
  // Do something with Data
}
console.log(data) // I want to get data outside the initData function
export { initData };
```

Comment: Can you show the code of `productData.js`?

Comment: There are many solutions: EventBus, localStorage, vuex,...

Comment: Or you can access Product.vue data from Vue app instance.

Comment: @NimaEbrazeh actually in my da.js file there is nothing. I want to know how to get data from .vue via .js. Can you help me

Comment: @Radeanu Can you clarify by showing a bit of code..Because I'm new to vuejs so it's a bit difficult..thank you

Comment: @deskeay As soon as possible

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simplest way is:

**Product.vue**

```js
<script>
import { initData } from "./productData.js";

export default {
  name: "Product",
  props: {
    msg: String,
  },
  data() {
    return {
      apiRes: "",
    };
  },
  mounted() {
    // your api call
    this.apiRes = "Hi from server";
    initData(this.apiRes);
  },
};
</script>
```

**productData.js**

```js
let data = null;

function initData(apiRes) {
  data = apiRes;
  console.log(data); // Output: "Hi from server"
  // Do something with Data
  
  doSomethingWithData();
}

function doSomethingWithData() {
  // Your app logic that depends on data
  // Here data will have value from API
}

// Here data is always null

export { initData };
```

Comment: Thanks.. Now I want to get the data out of the function, how do I do it.

Comment: What you mean out ? `data` is available in entire file.

Comment: `let data = null . function initData(apiRes) {data = apiRes;} console.log(data);` I want to get the data outside the `initData` function. Can you help me one more time?

Comment: I just updated the question..can you review it for me.

Comment: `data` is available there, but is `null` until is not set in `initData` function, if you want to run some logic using `data`, you can do it after `console.log`.

Comment: I've updated, but it would be better if you explain exactly what you want to do with `data` and what is purpose of `productData.js` file.