# Passing a variable to a js file Vue3 before components load

Tags: javascript, import, vuejs3

My question ist based on the answer here: [Pass data from vue file to js file in vuejs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69180501/pass-data-from-vue-file-to-js-file-in-vuejs)

So I import a js variable containing all the methods of my vue object:

```
<script>
...
import ui from "@/scripts/ui"
...
```

and then I assign this variable with method definitions to the object's methods:

```
export default {
  ...
  methods: { ...ui }
}
```

and here the content of the js file:

```
var ui = {

    method1() {...},

    method2() {...}
    ...

}

export default ui;
```

that works well

Now what I'm trying to do is to pass a variable containing some methods (called here methodImplementations) to this ui.js file so that I can reuse is on different elements and easily change the implementation of its methods. So it looks like this:

```
<script>
import methodsImplementations from "@/scripts/methodsImps";
import ui from "@/scripts/ui";
import { initMethImps } from "@/scripts/ui";

export default {
  ...
  mounted() {
    this.initMethImps(this.methodsImplementations);
  },
};
</script>
```

here the methodsImps.js file:

```
var methodsImplementations = {

    doSomething(){...}

}

export default methodsImplementations;
```

and here the new ui.js file

```
var meth_imps = null;

function initMethImps(methods) {
  meth_imps = methods;
}

var ui = {

    method1() {
        meth_imps.doSomething();
    },

    method2() {...}
    ...

}

export { initMethImps, ui };
```

The problem is that some components require some of the methods from methodsImps.js when they get created. I tried moving my code from mounted() to created() but it doesn't see the imports to use.

I it even possible to do it this way?

Thanks in advance!